# Distance between to points on opposite sides of a plane is greater then distance between the points and the plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given two points $P$ and $Q$ on opposite sites of a plane $H: n^T \cdot x = a$. I want to show that $||P-Q|| \ge d(P, H)$.

I know that $d(P, H) = \frac{n\cdot \overline{OP}}{||n||} + a$ and that $n^T \cdot P > 0$ and $n^T \cdot Q < 0$, but I don't know how to deduce from this that $d(P, H) \ge ||P-Q||$?

Comment: To go from $P$ to $Q$, you have to cross $H$.  By the time you get to $H$ (never mind continuing further to $Q$), you've already gone at least the distance $d(P,H)$, because this is the shortest distance from $P$ to any point in $H$.

Comment: yes, its clear to me, but how to make it formal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we can calmly assume that $a=0$, that is, $0\in H$, since distance is invariant under translation by any vector. Also assume that $||n||=1$. Then we have

$$d(P,H)=n\cdot P \le n\cdot P-n\cdot Q=n\cdot (P-Q)\le ||P-Q||\,.$$